Cookies authentication not working / User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always returning false
In my login webpage when a user logs in for some reason when I try to get the user's identity after it always returns false, this is weird because when I check for cookies ( I will provide and example) the program finds them. I'll provide the code for my logic page and also examples of cases where I check for the identity or cookies.
Login page:
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager _customUserManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    [BindProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email format")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public LoginModel(UserManager customUserManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _customUserManager = customUserManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ErrorMessage = null;
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Attempting login for email: {Email}");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var user = _customUserManager.AuthenticateUser(Email, Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"User {Email} logged in successfully.");

            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserID.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role) 
        };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60)
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("IsAuthenticated", "true");

            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid Username or Password. Please Try Again.";
        return Page();
    }
}

LoginPartial while with the nav bar ( here I tried using if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) but it always returns null so I just did the following which works for checking if the user is logged in or not:
@{
    bool isAuthenticated = Context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
}

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <form id="logoutForm" method="post" asp-page="/Logout">
                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?')">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/ShoppingCart">Shopping Cart</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Profile">Profile Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

My current issue is that I want to create a "Comple Order" page, where I get the user's Identity but it's always null so I'm currently stuck trying to fix the Identity issue:
public class OrderModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;

    public List<Item> CartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal DeliveryFee { get; set; }
    public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public string FreeAccessory { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public OrderModel(ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService, UserManager userManager)
    {
        _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        CartItems = _shoppingCartService.GetCartItems();
        TotalPrice = CartItems.Sum(item => item.Price);

        var user = _userManager.GetCurrentUser(HttpContext.User);
        AccountStatus = user.Role; 

        if (AccountStatus == "Premium")
        {
            DeliveryFee = 0;
            FreeAccessory = GetRandomAccessory();
        }
        else
        {
            DeliveryFee = 5; 
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(string Address, string PaymentInfo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(PaymentInfo))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Please fill in all the fields.";
            OnGet();
            return Page();
        }

        _shoppingCartService.ClearCart();

        return RedirectToPage("/OrderConfirmation");
    }

    private string GetRandomAccessory()
    {
        var accessories = new List<string> { "Keychain", "Helmet", "Stickers" };
        var random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(accessories.Count);
        return accessories[index];
    }
}

I tried just looking for cookies which worked for just changing the navigation bar but since I want to expand my program to allow users to make orders I have to fix this issue.

A couple of questions: 1. What does AuthenticateUser do? 2. Can you share your services.AddAuthentication code? Is the DefaultSignInScheme set to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;?

This is the code for my services.AddAuthentication:
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
options.LoginPath = "/Login";
options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
});

We have an official sample for cookie authentication in asp.net core in this document. Just like what you did in your codes, the sample also used HttpContext.SignInAsync to sign in user and create cookie like below.
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
                    authProperties);

However, in the sample, it gets user profile via HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims like below.
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;

@if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated!)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Hello @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FullName")?.Value!</h1>
            <p>Username: @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}  

I also test it in my side which worked well to getting the Role Claim.

